# Trouble passing form to module in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a click event on a form in Access 2010 that looks like so:

```
Private Sub SaveRecord_Click()
     checkDataIntegrity(Me)
End Sub
```

Where `checkDataIntegrity` is defined as follows:

```
Function checkDataIntegrity(ByVal fForm As form) As Boolean
```

This works fine and dandy.  However, I have another click event:

```
Private Sub LFS_Flashed_Successfully_Fail_Click()
     preventSimultaneousPassAndFail (Me)
End Sub
```

Where `preventSimultaneousPassAndFail` is defined as follows:

```
Function preventSimultaneousPassAndFail(ByVal fForm As form) As Boolean
```

When I invoke this click event I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '13':
Type mismatch
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Both event calls are invoked in the same form and call functions in the same module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be doing anything with the functions' return values, so don't enclose the arguments in parentheses.

```vb
'preventSimultaneousPassAndFail (Me)
preventSimultaneousPassAndFail Me
```

That is standard VBA practice.  Unfortunately, I can't explain why it triggered an error in one case but not the other.  So this issue may not contribute to the problem, but I still suggest you make that change to rule it out.

Although we don't know any details about those functions, I suggest you consider passing the form objects `ByRef` instead of `ByVal`.

Comment: Thank you.  This solved my problem.  access-vba (or maybe all vba) is frustratingly bad with its error messages.

Comment: `ByRef` or `ByVal` does not make any difference with respect to the error at hand. Passing parameters `ByRef` is needed just in the rare cases where the called method has to be able to change the value passed by the caller. In case of a reference to an object that's most likely not what someone would want. The properties of object passed into can be changed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get the error is that in the case of

```
preventSimultaneousPassAndFail (Me)
```

the parenthesis expression tries to invoke the default member of the object. In case of an Access.Form this is the Name property being of type String. That's the reason for the type mismatch error.

In case of

```
preventSimultaneousPassAndFail Me
```

the reference to the form itself is passed to the method.